# Not getting get_secret_value_response from client.get_secret_value()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nonetype, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to get secret but i am getting exception - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable as I'm not getting secret from get_secret_value.
Below are my codes:

class OracleConnection:
"""
This is a helper class for making authenticated connections to Oracle.
"""
def **init**(self):
self.evars = os.environ
print("1")
self.secret_name = self.evars.get("ORACLE_SECRET_ARN", "cci-acoe-secrets-dss-oracle-uet-dev")
self.region_name = self.evars.get("REGION", "us-east-1")
self.encoding = 'UTF-8'
self.connection = None
self.pool = None

```
def get_secret(self):
    global secret
    print("2")
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    print("3")
    client = session.client(
        config=config,
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=self.region_name
    )
    print("4")
    try:
        print(self.secret_name)
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=self.secret_name
        )
        print(get_secret_value_response)
        print("5")
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            raise e
    else:
        print("6")
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret_val = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            secret_val = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
        secret = json.loads(secret_val)


def __enter__(self):
    """
    This method opens the Oracle connection.
    """
    logger.debug("OracleConnection initializing connection with Oracle.")
    logger.debug("Gathering Oracle credentials.")
    try:
        print("7")
        self.get_secret()
        print(secret)
        info = {
            'user': secret['username'],
            'password': secret['password'],
            'host': secret['host'],
            'service': secret['dbname'],
            'port': int(secret['port'])
        }
        # Make DSN address
        self.user = info.get('user')
        self.pwd  = info.get('password')
        self.host = info.get('host')
        self.port = info.get('port')
        self.service = info.get('service')
        self.dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.host, self.port, service_name=self.service)

        # Create the session pool
        self.pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(
            self.user,
            self.pwd,
            self.dsn,
            min=100,
            max=100,
            increment=0,
            encoding=self.encoding
        )

        # Acquire a connection from the pool
        self.connection = self.pool.acquire()
        print(self.connection.version)

    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        logger.critical("Failed to establish Oracle connection.\nError: {}".format(error))
        raise

    logger.debug("Opening Oracle Connection.")
    return self
```

```
It's printing 1 2 3 4 also secret name but don't know why i am not getting any response from client.get_secret_value()? Please someone help.
```

Comment: What is the full error message and which line it originates from exactly?

Comment: get_secret() is having None in global secret variable. client.get_secret_value() is not returning any response it seems

Comment: The `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` must have different origin. Can you provide full error message and which line exactly it originates from?

Comment: def __enter__(self):
        """
        This method opens the Oracle connection.
        """
        logger.debug("OracleConnection initializing connection with Oracle.")
        logger.debug("Gathering Oracle credentials.")
        try:
            print("7")
            self.get_secret()
            info = {
                'user': secret['username'],
                'password': secret['password'],
                'host': secret['host'],
                'service': secret['dbname'],
                'port': int(secret['port'])
            }

Comment: Can you edit the question with new details. Also you still have provided **full** error message and specified **exactly** the line it originates from.

Comment: I have made some edits please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  Is your lambda attached to a VPC?  If so, make sure you choose public subnets for it.  It has something to do with private subnets cannot connect to the internet...and your secrets manager call will not work.  I am also figuring this out.